# Browsers don't refresh html

Tags: html

I'm building a website whose hosting supports only html and javascript. I've corrected some mistakes but visitors probably won't see them because browsers can't show the updated pages. They show the old pages.

I remember "html expires" code but it's too late. Because many visitors saw our site.

Comment: A manual refresh in the browser should always reload the page. Why do you think it would not?

Comment: I don't see a question in there... Did you mean to ask how you can rectify the issue?

Comment: This is not about a manual refresh - it's the *visitors* that need to see the updated content.

Comment: yes, i wonder how visitors can see updated pages

Comment: Have you uploaded templates to the server after editing them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your *HTML* files aren't being updated and not CSS style sheets or JS files (for which the answer would be different).

This is mainly a server side issue - you would have to check with your hosting provider what caching headers the server emits. Ideally, the server would listen to `if-modified-since` requests from browsers so it can serve updated content if there is any, and make the browser use the cached copy if there is none.

To remedy the problem at hand, you may need to rename your existing HTML files, or put them in a new directory. That will force the browser to actively re-fetch them. Of course, that still means that the entry point (usually `index.html`) will have to be re-fetched by the client - otherwise they will never notice the new structure, and hence not re-load anything.

A hosting configuration that indiscriminately dishes out caching instructions that prevent frequent updates from being made is not really useful. Talking to your hosting provider would probably be a good idea.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. i'll talk to my hosting provider. the idea of renaming files is interesting. thanks again.